Blitz cache randomly deleting
I run blitz cache with the "clear cache regenerate manually or organically setting". We have a big site with over 7000 entries, and this works best as the entire site can be cached and it's updated by users editing pages and refreshing to show recent changes. We also run blitz/cache/refresh-expired nightly as a cron job.
What I'm confused about is the full cache is randomly deleted during the day, sometimes once and sometimes 3 or 4 times and we have to manually regenerate it. I don't know what is triggering this, we do a lot of content so there can be lot of page creation and updates everyday so maybe that's a factor
Thanks for any insights

You haven’t asked a question, so I’ll just note that the Blitz Diagnostics utility can be used to better understand how your site’s cached content is structured, allowing you to optimise the caching strategy and overall performance of your site. Perhaps it will also help explain why some content changes are clearing out the entire cache.

Yes that report is very useful, I noticed the "refreshCacheWhenElementMovedInStructure": true  setting. This is the reason behind the cache deletions as my users regularly move elements in structure. It's good to know what's is happening with it and I presume I can turn this off in the blitz config if I need to

Yes, you sure can.

I just want to follow up on this on, I added refreshCacheWhenElementMovedInStructure'=> false to my blitz config and it's showing up in my blitz diagnostics as an active rule. But I have noticed that if a user drags an entry to move it in structure it clears the cache automatically. But if they use the choose parent option to move an entry that way its doesn't affect the cache.

Thanks for the observation. If you could create an issue with more details at https://github.com/putyourlightson/craft-blitz/issues then I’ll gladly look into it.
